# Text indent command

Tags: indentation

Good Morning.
I would like to build a code to get what you see in the picture, creating a single command for "Lorem" and one for "Ipsum". Is this possible? Thank you.
[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why do you need separate commands for something that looks exactly the same?

Comment: Is there a constraint on the overall width of the desired layout? E.g., should the overall width be equal to `\textwidth`? Please advise.

Comment: you can use a latex description environment customise the layout with enumitem

Comment: @Plergux  Ok ok a single command is fine too. Thank you.

Comment: @ Mico  No constraint!

Comment: @AndyToff  does the answer below satisfy your requirement --using the package `enumitem` widths can be set to generate different output -- showframe has been incorporated only for checks and can be deleted / removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without LaTeX packages:

```
\def\loremis{Loerm Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
  industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's starndard dummy text ever
  since 1500s, when an unknown printer took a gallery of type and scrambed it
  to make a type specimen book.}

\def\p #1 {\noindent\hbox to5em{#1\hfil}\hangindent=5em \hangafter=1 }

\p Lorem \loremis
\bigskip
\p Ipsum \loremis

\bye
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `tabularx`-based solution. A "degree of freedom" in this setup is the width of the first column. In the code below, the width is set to `0.75in`; obviously, you're free to choose whatever length you like best.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,lipsum}
\newcommand\mydesc[2]{#1 & #2 \\ \addlinespace}
\begin{document}

\noindent % <-- may be omitted if `\parindent` is equal to 0pt
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} w{l}{0.75in} >{\RaggedRight}X @{}}
\mydesc{Lorem}{\lipsum[1][1-4]}
\mydesc{Ipsum}{\lipsum[2][1-3]}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, ]{report}
\usepackage[showframe,]{geometry}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\chapter*{Using package enumitem}

\begin{description}[labelindent=0pt,labelwidth=2.1cm,labelsep*=1em,leftmargin=!]
    \item[Lorem] \lipsum[2][1-4]
    \item[Ipsum] \lipsum[1][1-3]
    \end{description}

\end{document}
```