# How to align text vertically into two sections?

Tags: sectioning, tex-core, two-column, columns

Ho do I achieve the following effect with TeX?

```
Czech       Spoken in Czech Republic 
Ukrainian   Spoken in Ukraine
Azerbaijani Spoken in Azerbaijan
English     Spoken in many many many many many many many many many many many many
            many many many many many many countries
Italian     Spoken in Italia
```

Comment: I am not sure if I interpret the question correctly but you may be looking for `paracol`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). Two options are to use a `descrption` list, or `tabular`.  A recent similar question: [Text indent command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/574434/4301) may answer your question.

Comment: @SashaShpota please see the answer below if it meets the requirement

Comment: @jsbibra thank you, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, ]{report}
\usepackage[]{geometry}

\usepackage{enumitem, calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\newlength{\mylength}
\settowidth{\mylength}{Azerbaijani}
%\the\mylength
\begin{description}[labelindent=0pt,labelwidth=\mylength+10pt,labelsep*=1em,leftmargin=!]
\item[Czech]       Spoken in Czech Republic 
\item[Ukrainian]   Spoken in Ukraine
\item[Azerbaijani] Spoken in Azerbaijan
\item[English]     Spoken in many many many many many many many many many many many many
many many many many many many countries
\item[Italian]     Spoken in Italia
    \end{description}
\end{document}
```

**Edit if you do not require bold font in label**

add the following line

```
\setlist[description]{font=\normalfont}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, ]{report}
\usepackage[]{geometry}

\usepackage{enumitem, calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\newlength{\mylength}
\settowidth{\mylength}{Azerbaijani}

\setlist[description]{font=\normalfont}

\begin{description}[labelindent=0pt,labelwidth=\mylength+10pt,labelsep*=1em,leftmargin=!]
\item[Czech]       Spoken in Czech Republic 
\item[Ukrainian]   Spoken in Ukraine
\item[Azerbaijani] Spoken in Azerbaijan
\item[English]     Spoken in many many many many many many many many many many many many
many many many many many many countries
\item[Italian]     Spoken in Italia
    \end{description}
\end{document}
```

Result--

[image]

If you have a word label longer than `Azerbaijani` in your labels simply replace the longest word in the line

```
\settowidth{\mylength}{Azerbaijani}
```

and the new label width will be automatically computed